# How can I import data using props with Svelte for this reusable gallery I'm building?

Tags: javascript, components, svelte, sveltekit

I'm building a reusable gallery using Svelte. All else is done but I have multiple galleries so multiple sets of image data and I can't figure out how to pass the image data in as a prop. Anyways the code should better show what I mean.

I have a .js file for the image data:

```
//rocketgallery.js
export const images = [
    {
        id: 0,
        alt: "Zack and Alex arming a rocket.",
        src: "img/gallery/rocket1.jpg"
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        alt: "Zack and Matt performing parachute testing.",
        src: "img/gallery/rocket2.jpg"
    }
]
```

the gallery component itself (I'm just showing how I'd like to import the images [which obviously doesn't work]):

```
//slidegallery.svelte
    export let gallerydata = {gallerydata}
    import {images} from gallerydata
```

and the little snippet to insert a gallery:

```
//in index.svelte
  import Slidegallery from '$lib/components/slidegallery.svelte'

  <Slidegallery gallerydata='../data/rocketgallery.js' size='20vw' position='left' display='wrap'/>
  <Slidegallery gallerydata='../data/anothergallery.js' size='20vw' position='center' display='block'/>
```

So as you can see I'm trying to indicate what images I want in each gallery in the index page, and my component is looking to import the images from the path specified. I've been stuck on this for a bit so any direction would be a great help. I'm not sure if my entire approach to this is wrong or whether this is a simple syntax problem. Either way, pre-thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably make do with dynamic imports but, given the form of your data, it seems easier and more straightforward to turn them into JSON and load them with `fetch`.

First you'd convert your galleries data to JSON files and put them in the `static` directory, to make them available for download. For example:

`static/galleries/gallery1.json`

```json
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "alt": "Zack and Alex arming a rocket.",
        "src": "img/gallery/rocket1.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "alt": "Zack and Matt performing parachute testing.",
        "src": "img/gallery/rocket2.jpg"
    }
]
```

Then, you could make a gallery component like this:

```html
<script>
    export let gallery;

    const loadGallery = (name) =>
        fetch(`/galleries/${gallery}.json`)
            .then((res) => {
                if (!res.ok) throw new Error('Fetch error');
                return res;
            })
            .then((res) => res.json());

    $: imagesPromise = gallery && loadGallery(gallery);
</script>

{#if imagesPromise}
    {#await imagesPromise then images}
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(images, null, 2)}</pre>
    {:catch err}
        <pre>{err}</pre>
    {/await}
{/if}
```

---

If you really want your galleries data to be some JavaScript, you could pass dynamic imports to your components like this:

```html
<SlideGallery gallery={import('../data/rocketgallery.js')} ... />
```

Your component would then receive a promise that would resolve to the JS module. You could use them like this, for example:

`SlideGallery.svelte`

```html
<script>
    export let gallery;
</script>

{#if gallery}
    {#await gallery then imageModule}
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(imageModule.images, null, 2)}</pre>
    {:catch err}
        <pre>{err}</pre>
    {/await}
{/if}
```

Notice that, for this to work, you need to pass *static strings* (i.e. not strings that are constructed with code or some string in a variable) to your dynamic imports, because otherwise the bundler won't "see" them.

```js
// works because the bundler sees the full URL
import('../data/gallery.js')

// doesn't work because the bundler doesn't see the URL hidden
// in the dynamic string, and so the import won't be rewritten 
// to what it'll really be in your bundled app
import('../data/' + 'gallery.js')
```

Or alternatively, you could put raw `.js` files in the `static`, so that you can know their actual runtime URLs.